# Mann-Whitney Test

Tags: dataset, comparison

I have a question about Mann-Whitney test. Could anyone please help me to answer my following questions and I will be very grateful with your help.

I want to compare the differences between the two dataset of respondents’ satisfaction. One dataset uses the scale from 1 to 5, and 1 is very dissatisfied, and 5 is very satisfied, and 3 is neutral.

Another dataset uses the scale from -5 to 5 (-5,-4,-3,-2,0,2,3,4,5), in which -5 is very dissatisfied, 0 is neutral, 5 is very satisfied.

My questions are:

1. Can I compare the differences of these two dataset as they are used
   different scales?
2. If I can compare, how can I re-scale them?

I’ll be grateful with your help and looking forward to your reply.

Kind Regards,

Weijia

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about statistics and not programming.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I compare the differences of these two dataset as they are used different scales?

That depends on how rigid you need to be.
Any change in the data collection method could affect the way people answer, so the significance/precision of the comparison is reduced. Since the target is a customer satisfaction survey and not a study of some new medicine, I'd say that you can compare them provided you point out that one dataset has been rescaled.

> If I can compare, how can I re-scale them?

I would probably do it like this:

```
1 -->  -5
2 -->  -3
3 -->   0
4 -->  +3
5 -->  +5
```